# Maximize windows just like Windows on OS X

Tags: macos, macbook, shortcuts, window

I am an owner of a Macbook Pro for a year already. But at work I work with a Windows laptop. And since I really like the functionality to maximize a windows with just pushing it to the top of the screen, I would like to have that on my Macbook too.

I am using Spectacle to assign shortcuts like windows to maximize a window, I would really recommend that.

But is there an application to maximize a window the way you can do it on a Windows laptop/pc, just by pushing the window to the top of the screen?

I would really like that.

**Note: I mean maximize window, not fullscreen.**

Answer (score 0):

I use BetterSnapTool. I have been using it for more than a year and am very happy with it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you expand your answer a bit? Just pointing to a product doesn't really explain how to accomplish the solution, and it's often viewed as spam. It's better to include some instructions on how to use the product to solve the problem, or at least describe what makes the product a good solution. Good guidance on recommending software here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers.  Thanks.